# Angular8 animations - expand element width in a drag and drop fashion

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-animations

I looked for a similar question but found none, so:

I have a slider element - like the ones on a video player that allows to control the current location on the playing video.
I want to expand/shrink the slider following a left drag or right drag from one of the slider's edges.
I tried to use the "old" way of "mousedown"/"mouseup" event handling, but I rather use the Angular way.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div
        id="scene-slider">
        <button (click)="shiftLeft()" class="slider-left-handle">
            <div class="handle-label"></div>
        </button>
        <div
            class="scene-length-label">
        </div>
        <button class="slider-right-handle">
            <div class="handle-label"></div>
        </button>
    </div>
```

When a user moves the mouse following a click on the 'slider-right-handle' I wish to have a drag effect that will result in the 'scene-slider' to change its width in the move direction.